# What's the best regex for validating a field?

Tags: php, regex, user-generated-content

I use a regular expression to on a user-inputted field to make sure that they have entered between 1 and 20 characters.

Here's the code:

```
$post_validations = array("title" => '/^[[:alnum:][:punct:][:space:]]{1,100}$/');
```

But whenever a user enters a foreign character, or a special quote character from MS Word (I can't paste it into here, it converts it to a normal quote!) the regex doesn't return true, and it shows an error.

I wondered what would be the best regex to use?

Thanks

Comment: Which function do you use to evaluate the expression? PCRE or POSIX? Because you are using POSIX character classes. In any way, you should switch to PCRE. And what is the error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If all you want is know that it is between 1 and 20 characters, why not use [`strlen()`](http://php.net/strlen) ?

```
 $length = strlen($title);
 if($length >= 1 and $length <=20)
      echo "VALID";
 else
      echo "Invalid";
```

---

**[EDIT]: Checking whether aplhanumeric or puctuation:**

And if you also want to check whether the string contains any non-printable characters that may cause problem, just use [`ctype_graph()`](http://php.net/ctype_graph)

```
 if(ctype_graph ($title))
      echo "Only alphanumeric or punctuation";
 else
      echo "Invalid non-printable characters found";
```

**[EDIT 2]:**

If you also want the spaces    to be validated, just use this:

```
if(ctype_graph(str_replace(' ', '',$title))
```

Comment: It seems the OP wants to allow spaces - which `ctype_graph()` doesn't allow.